# equest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefetch'

Tags: python, django

the following code:

```
response = requests.post(settings.SAGEPAY_URL, data=request_body,
                                     prefetch=True, verify=True)
```

gives this error:

```
request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefetch'
```

why and how to resolve?

Thanks

PS I'm running Django 1.5.1

Comment: prefetch is not a valid keyword argument for requests.post would be my guess ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter was changed to stream: http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#api-changes